# Sparx EA.App doesn't reflect Activator.CreateInstance properly

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I've got .NET Framework 4.6.2 console app that is accessing Sparx Enterprise Architect repository. The code below shows a simple example of using Activator.CreateInstance(). The problem is that when creating a second instance the current one (stored in eaApp) is used, so I cannot access two different repositories. Is there any witted solution to this problem?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EA.App eaApp = (EA.App)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("EA.App", true));
    EA.App eaApp2 = (EA.App)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("EA.App", true));
    eaApp.Repository.OpenFile(@"c:\Temp\UCI2.EAP");
    eaApp2.Repository.OpenFile(@"c:\Temp\UCI3.EAP");
    EA.Element test = eaApp.Repository.GetElementByGuid("{53F2ADAE-E8AC-40da-A06F-D64F525B87E8}");
    EA.Element test2 = eaApp2.Repository.GetElementByGuid("{DBF0459F-0662-4e5b-B7E3-A065087B624E}");


    Console.WriteLine($"test1: {test.Notes} test2: {test2.Notes}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like Sparx is handing you a Singleton.

Comment: How exactly do you know that eaApp and eaApp2 refer to the same object instance and not to two different object instances which just happen to represent the same data?

Comment: I was thinking `EA.App` contains some shared static members.  Different instances, but shared state.

Comment: What is the value of `?eaApp == eaApp2` from the `Immediate Window`?

Comment: @elgonzo  Well, there is just one process. When asking for test, null is returned (when I get rid of second OpenFile, in test is a proper value).

Comment: @mjwills the return value is false.

Comment: From this thread on the Sparx forums: https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=36016.0, it seems `EA.App` always likes to connect to one particular running EA instance, even if there are several running. Unfortunately, the participants in the thread were unable to find a solution to associate different `EA.App` objects with different running EA instances :-( (i agree with mjwills, the title of your question is misleading)

Comment: Well, Activator.CreateInstance doesn't work in a strange manner. It just does what it always does: creating object instances (unless you want to call that strange). If something does work in a strange manner, it is only EA.App. ;-)

Comment: @mjwills, do you think so? My comment more or less was just a link to a Sparx forum thread, with the last entry being from October 2016. I don't really know EA to tell what has and what has not changed in the two years since, so i am a bit hesitant to write an answer that could be mistaken as some definitive statement about the current state of things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new instance do something like this

```
 EA.Repository r = new EA.Repository();

 r.OpenFile("c:\\eatest.eap");
```

As described in the [manual](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/automation_connect_setup.html)

Connecting to the (first) running instance can be done like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
object obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("EA.App");
var eaApp = obj as EA.App;
var myRepository = eaApp?.Repository;
```